# How do I use the host as DNS with Android / ADB?

Tags: android, dns, adb

I'm using the Android Debug Bridge (ADB) to connect my unrooted Droid M (Android 4.1.2) to my Mac (Mavericks) via USB and the following ppp connection:

```
sudo `which adb` ppp "shell:pppd nodetach noauth noipdefault /dev/tty" nodetach noauth noipdefault notty 192.168.0.100:192.168.0.200
```

(source: [commandlinefu.com](http://www.commandlinefu.com/commands/view/10355/creates-a-ppp-link-between-my-ubuntu-development-machine-and-beagleboard-running-android-connected-via-usb))

On my Mac, I'm using Vagrant to run a web server stack and the Mac's host files to redirect hostnames like `app.myserver.com` and `api.myserver.com` to point to the Vagrant box (which all works fine).

Here's my question: Is there a way I can connect my Droid M to my Mac in a way that uses the Mac as the DNS and thus would properly route the domain names in the Mac's hosts file?

I thought I had this working on another machine about a year ago, but I can't figure out how I did it.

Thanks,
-Nate

Comment: Are you using your Mac as a hotspot for your Android device to connect to - or are you already doing that?

Comment: @MorrisonChang, I'm connected to the Mac via USB. I'm not doing anything with wifi.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this?

Answer (score -1):

run your apis on 10.0.2.2 ip. at emulator it will communicate with your local web server same as 127.0.0.1 at desktop.

Comment: I can't seem to ping 10.0.2.2 from within the phone's shell (i.e. `adb shell`). And since the phone is unrooted, I can't edit its hosts file to add the domain entries for the phone.

Comment: this ip "10.0.2.2" will work only on emulator. if you run it at your emulator then it will point to your desktop machine's localhost. so that you can test your web apis locally. this IP will not work on actual device because device has it own ip.

Comment: I either don't understand, or we're talking about two different things. I want to access the Vagrant box on the host (Mac) from the guest (Android) by using the Mac as the DNS server so it's hosts file makes the proper DNS resolutions. It doesn't really matter what the phone IP Address is.